# How to tell gruntfile to just test phantomJS on a pull request

Tags: github, gruntjs, karma-runner, travis-ci, saucelabs

I have been having `pull request` failing on Travis/SauceLabs while the `merge` build works good. When I get a pull request Travis fails with this code:

```
ERROR [launcher.sauce]: Can not start chrome (linux)
  Failed to start Sauce Connect:
  Could not start Sauce Connect. Exit code 1 signal: null
```

How can I test incoming pull requests just on Travis and test a `merge` on SauceLabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **[not possible yet](http://support.saucelabs.com/entries/25614798-How-can-we-set-up-an-open-source-account-that-runs-tests-on-people-s-pull-requests-)** to run pull requests on Sauce Labs when the sauce key/pass are encrypted. This is for safety reasons to not expose the credentials in case the PR has malicious code.

So what is possible is to use the

```
process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST // (string)
```

to distinguish a pull request from a push/merge triggered test.

So, since this [**enviroment variable**](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables) gives you a **string** with the *pull request number* or with `"false"`, its possible to use it as a flag. So I used this on my Gruntfile:

```
var pullRequest = process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST;
tasks =  pullRequest != 'false' ? 'karma:continuous' : 'karma:sauceTask';
grunt.registerTask('default:travis', tasks);
```

and in my `:continuous` task I have only PhantomJS

```
        continuous: {
            browsers: ['PhantomJS']
        },
```